# How to fix "ambiguous method call" in my code in Java in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm following the tutorial for play framework in Java (#13) on youtube and I stuck in Index Method of BookStore Application. I cant go any further since I get: "Ambiguous method call. Both render(Set,) in index and render(Set) in index$ match".

I tried to change Set for List but the massage I got was basically the same only in relation to List.

```
public class BooksController extends Controller {

    public Result index(){
        Set<Book> books = Book.allBooks();

        return ok(index.render(books));  //<--------- the error
    }        
}

public class Book {

    public Integer id;
    public String title;
    public Integer price;
    public String author;

    public Book(Integer id, String title,Integer price, String author){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public static Set<Book> books;

    static {
        books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(new Book(1, "Java", 20, "ABC"));
        books.add(new Book(2,"C++", 30, "XYZ"));
    }

    public  static Set<Book> allBooks(){
        return books;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you also show us your index template?

Comment: this is my template : @(books:Set[Book])
<html>
    <head>
        <title>All Books</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>All books</h1>
        @for(book <- books){
            <p>Title: @book.title</p>

        }
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because `index` from `views.html.index.render` and your method `index()` in BooksController have same name and compiler is confused what method to use. Just change name of your render method to something else for example `booksIndex()` and your problem will be gone.

```
public class BooksController extends Controller {

    public Result booksIndex(){
        Set<Book> books = Book.allBooks();

        return ok(index.render(books));
    }        
}
```

P.S. don't forget to change your routes file after

Comment: I have followed your suggestions and unfortunately still it doesn't work. Moreover later I have changed the name of the template for booksIndex. This time I get the message:"Ambiguous method call. Both render(Set<Book>,) in booksIndex and render(Set<Book>) in booksIndex$ match"

Comment: Do you have correct import in your controller file? like `views.html.index.render`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I imported:package controllers;
import models.Book;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.books.booksIndex;
import java.util.Set;